# Is there any inbuilt search bar in the googleMaps?

Tags: ios

I want to add search bar on top of GoogleMap, I added programatically but i am thinking of inbuilt SearchBar might available in GoogleMap sdk. Please give suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can open

> GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController you can use  in your code but you can't place this search bar in your map page top.

[link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_results_controller)